# Reading a formatted file step-by-step using python

Tags: python-3.x, database

In my curent project, I need to read a special file which look as so:

```
name_countdown1{YYYY-MM-DD}
name_countdown2{YYYY-MM-DD} ...
```

I must handle each line one by one. And need to separate every data (name, year, month, day). Sometimes, I'll need to delete some line
I can't find an efficient way to process those data.

Is this format appropriate for python?
How could I read them efficiently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, Fist of all, if you would like to delete a line or in general create a modified version of the file you're processing, best way is to create a new file, holding the new changes, in python to do that you can simply:

```
with open(input_file, 'r') as infile, open(temp_file, 'w') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        if condition:
            # writing in the outfile means you keep the line, else line is removed
            outfile.write(line)
```

Secondly, an efficient way to capture the data separately is to use regular expressions, as i understood your data, lines are like this: "somename_YYYY-MM-DD", For that, the end code would be something like this:

```
import re

pattern = r'(\w+)_(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})'
match = re.search(pattern, line)
if match:
    name = match.group(1)
    year = int(match.group(2))
    month = int(match.group(3))
    day = int(match.group(4))
```

Comment: Is the "line" variable already existing? Or should I determinate it?

Comment: you can see the line variable in the first code i provided, "for line in infile:"
the second code should be contained within the first code, i just seperated them for clarity

Comment: Ok but in the first code "line" is an existing variable in "infile"?

Comment: Yea, we opened the file, and read it line by line, and each "line" variable is processed as shown in the second code, and we repeat until the end of the file.

Comment: Ok nice. Is there a way to specify that spaces, comma and dash are considers as character? (In french there is dashes in some words)

Comment: Yea, if you'd like to include french characters as well as spaces as part of the name variable, the regular expression would be like this: 
pattern = r'(.+?)_(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})'
The (.+?) will capture one or more of any character (except for a newline) between the underscore and the date.